# Extract information about method receiver from stack

Tags: ruby, stack-trace, trace

If we call `caller` method, we get something like:

```
prog.rb:3:in `a'
prog.rb:6:in `b'
prog.rb:9:in `c'
```

This is helpful for humans, but if I wanted to analyze the stack programmatically, not really, as two methods called `:a` may be entirely unrelated.

Is there any way/method to extract information about the receiver of the methods (like its class or object id) as well? For example:

```
prog.rb:3:in `Klass#a'
prog.rb:6:in `Modoole#b'
prog.rb:9:in `OtherKlass#c'
```

Formatting is only an example; this info might be an `Array` or anything.

I'm trying to emulate this with `TracePoint`, but forming a separate stack is a bad solution. Is there any Ruby way I missed in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to `Kernel#caller` named [`Kernel#caller_locations`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller_locations), that returns an array of [`Thread::Backtrace::Location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-label) objects. According to the manual, these should in theory be able to give you this information through the [`#label`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Thread/Backtrace/Location.html#method-i-label) method.

> Returns the label of this frame.
>
> Usually consists of method, class, module, etc names with decoration.

After trying this out however, I need to question the term *usually* in the docs, because it seems to only return the method name still. Unless *usually* means it works for you, there seems to be no way of accomplishing this as of now.

**Edit:**

As per comment, one case that satisfies the condition of *usually* is when the method call is coming from within a `Class` or `Module` body:

```
class A
  def trace
    puts caller_locations.first.label
  end
end

class B
  A.new.trace
end
#=> <class:B>

module C
  A.new.trace
end
#=> <module:C>
```

Comment: It seems _usually_ means 'when code is called directly from class body'.

Comment: Nice find @Borsunho. I've added it to the answer. I'll see if I can ask someone on Ruby core team about it.